# xpath search for multiple keywords

Tags: c#, xpath, html-agility-pack

I'm using the htmlagilitypack and xpath to scrape a webpage for particular keywords.  I'm running into trouble searching for more than one keyword at a time.

so the code I've got for the keyword stuff is (with randomly chosen keywords: Frozen and obamacare):

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
doc = web.Load(uri);
HtmlNodeCollection Nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//text()[contains(., 'Frozen obamacare')]");
```

this doesn't work even though I know the page in particular has both keywords, and from other findings was basically informed that `SelectNodes("//text()[contains(., 'Frozen obamacare')]");`  is the right way for multiple keywords.

I need help verifying if this is the correct way to utilize multiple keywords, and if it's not, then I am looking for help to correct it.

Comment: The query you're using isn't searching for multiple keywords, its searching for a string `Frozen obamacare`.  Try this `//text()[contains(.,'Frozen') and contains(.,'obamacare')]`

Comment: I chose Jens Erat's answer because it works right now, even though the XPath 2.0 capabilities are probably the best way to go, I would have to change what I have/am using or fix the errors that crop up when attempting the XPath 2.0 content.  Thank  you all for all the great help.  You guys are awesome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This retrieves all text nodes, that contain the string 'Frozen obamacare'. It does not tokenize to words or anything. Examples matching your query would be:

- Frozen obamacare
- fooFrozen obamacarebar

It would not match:

- Frozen foo obamacare
- Frozen-obamacare
- etc.

To match string in XPath 1.0 that contain both tokens, use

```
//text()[contains(., 'Frozen') and contains(., 'obamacare')]
```

HTML Agility Pack only supports XPath 1.0, so you cannot use the more advanced tokenization features of XPath 2.0.

Comment: Since the HTML Agility Pack only supports XPath 1.0 what could I use the XPath 2.0 with in order to have the HTML document capabilities that the Agility Pack has?

Comment: There is a bunch of XQuery/XPath 2.0 processors that can be interfaced from .net. Have a look at Saxon which provides native capabilities. BaseX also has interfaces. Theres another native .net library, but I don't remember the name right now. By the way, my answer is actually about XPath 1.0. In XPath 2.0, you would use `tokenize` on the source string.

Answer (score 1):

Your XPath `//text()[contains(., 'Frozen obamacare')]` checks for text nodes containing the string `Frozen obamacare` literally.

You might want to check whether you can use XPath 2.0 or XQuery 1.0 as that way you could use e.g. `//text()[matches(., 'Frozen|obamacare')]` or consider to use the LINQ support in .NET and HTML Agility Pack with regular expression support where you could use

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using HtmlAgilityPack;

namespace ConsoleApplication63
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
            HtmlDocument doc = web.Load("http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22767900/xpath-search-for-multiple-keywords");

            foreach (HtmlTextNode text in doc.DocumentNode.Descendants().OfType<HtmlTextNode>().Where(n => Regex.IsMatch(n.InnerText, @"\b(Frozen|obamacare)\b")))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Found \"{0}\"", text.InnerText);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: will this actually work with the HTML Agility Pack (I ask because I see it as part of your using statements)?

Comment: @shadonar, yes, sure, that is tested code using the latest version of the HTML Agility Pack taken from NuGet.